# How to burn both fat and muscle at the same time?

Tags: muscle, burn-fat, burn

After doing a body composition test the results show an abundance of both fat and muscle in my thighs. My thighs are really thick and short at the same time. I'd like to get a slimmer figure for aesthetic purposes. Specifically slimmer legs.

What type of exercise works best for the above purpose?

Comment: If your legs are naturally like that, based off your training. You should simply train your legs less, Just the way your genetics are. I know people who squat once a week for legs but still have good size and definition in their legs.

Comment: @IvoryAegis - Generally, the fitness industry works under the proven theory that you can NOT spot reduce fat. Do you have any peer-reviewed sources that say otherwise? I would be very interested to read about that research.

Comment: @IvoryAegis - Yeah, those are some interesting results. But as you mention, these studies are so small, it's gonna be hard to conclude anything for sure. n=16 in that one you linked is a bit of a small sample size to really change the paradigm, but hopefully this leads to further research, and from there, who knows.

Comment: From what I gather, cardio (like running on a treadmill) is a good way to burn fat and muscle. But I am still new...

Comment: This question is simply a differently worded version of “How to lose mass”, and the answer is simply to “be in a caloric deficit”. You could also train your legs less often or hard, but unless you are a new lifter (having an abundance of muscle says the opposite), then you won’t be growing much if any muscle on a deficit.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that you both have very muscular legs (which, unless you got there with drugs or exceptional genetics, suggests you know your stuff) and need to ask this question. So please get a second opinion beforehand about what's aesthetic and what's not. People tend to be horrible at judging their own bodies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the first time I've heard someone wants to lose both fat and muscle mass.

Of course there's a method to lose both fat and muscle: to be on a hypocaloric and low-protein diet ([Advanced Nutrition, 2017](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/28507015)). Such diet would very likely reduce fat and muscle in your body in general, not just in legs.

You can spot-reduce muscle mass in your thighs by using your legs less. Or you can try different trousers. It is said that clothes with vertical lines make you look taller and slimmer.

Spot reduction of body fat in your context does not make sense. Even if spot reduction of fat works, by training your thighs, you would lose fat but gain muscle in your thighs.

Fat distribution is genetically determined ([Science Daily, 2010](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2010/10/101010133620.htm)), so you lose fat from where you have it. [This article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/28497942) about spot reduction of body fat mentioned in the comments does not say what was the original fat distribution in 16 participants (all women, by the way).

Comment: Spot reduction of fat is possible if you go to a doctor for some liposuction. ;)

Comment: How much does it cost, what are the risks and how long does the effect last?

Comment: I think that's the sort of question you should ask a plastic surgeon - or maybe the Biology StackExchange? There doesn't seem to be a Medicine SE.

Comment: I was trying to say that liposuction is not really the first choice in such situations...

Answer (score 0):

well.i think i have same problem with you ,I am not very tall and of medium weight.I have a lot of fat around my waist.So I have to do a lot of weight loss training, such as flat support and so on.Specializing in waist training,If you want to lose your legs, you can search for videos about it on the Internet. Many yoga classes are also suitable for reducing leg muscles. You can also follow up several body exercises to achieve the plastic effect. After running, you must stretch your legs to relax your muscles and prevent leg muscles from accumulating.If you want to be effective, you still need to persevere, refuel and strive to be thin.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are patient of sugar and you should consult with a doctor for your body fitness and you should take  light morning walk and morning exercise and you should away from oily and non - vegetarian food l